# Custom kernel isn't printing on the screen correctly

Tags: string, gcc, x86, kernel, osdev

I'm having trouble getting strings to print on my custom kernel. I've been following a tutorial on github. So far, I can only print strings that are 5 characters or less, and can't directly pass a string as a parameter.

kernel.c

```
#include "../drivers/screen.h"

void main() {
  clear_screen();
  // This line does NOT work.
  kprint_at("X", 10, 10);

  // This line DOES work
  char msg[] = "X";
  kprint_at(msg, 10, 10);

  // This line does NOT work
  char msg[] = "123456"; // Will only work for strings less than 6 characters.
  kprint_at(msg, 10, 10);
}
```

screen.c

```
void kprint_at(char* message, int col, int row) {
  int offset;
  if (col >= 0 && row >= 0) offset = get_offset(col, row);
  else {
    offset = get_cursor_offset();
    row = get_offset_row(offset);
    col = get_offset_col(offset);
  }

  int i = 0;
  while (message[i] != 0) {
    offset = print_char(message[i++], col, row, WHITE_ON_BLACK);
    row = get_offset_row(offset);
    col = get_offset_col(offset);
  }
}

int print_char(char c, int col, int row, char attr) {
  unsigned char* vidmem = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_ADDRESS;
  if (!attr) attr = WHITE_ON_BLACK;

  if (col >= MAX_COLS || row >= MAX_ROWS) {
    vidmem[2*(MAX_COLS)*(MAX_ROWS)-2] = 'E';
    vidmem[2*(MAX_COLS)*(MAX_ROWS(-1] = RED_ON_WHITE;
    return get_offset(col, row);
  }

  int offset;
  if (col >= 0 && row >= 0) offset = get_offset(col, row);
  else offset = get_cursor_offset();

  if (c == '\n') {
    row = get_offset_row(offset);
    offset = get_offset(0, row+1);
  } else {
    vidmem[offset] = c;
    vidmem[offset+1] = attr;
    offset += 2;
  }
  set_cursor_offset(offset);
  return offset;
}
```

If i set the row or col to beyond the width or height of the screen, I do get a red E at the bottom right corner, so I know that's working properly. Also, if I set the word to start near the end of the screen, it continues on the next line. It just won't let me input the string directly into the kprint_at function, and won't let me use any strings greater than 5 characters. Any ideas on whats going on?

I am using c language, with assembly. I'm also using a 64-bit linux system, but I'm running my kernel in 32-bit protected mode. Using a gcc cross compiler (i386-elf-gcc).

Comment: If you are using a custom bootloader are you reading enough sectors to read the entire kernel including the data? Or are you using GRUB?